# Allow user to make only one active login using salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

In salesforce, can we allow specific user to login one at a time globally ? If he is login into the salesforce already, then he should not be able to login again, unless first active login gets loggoff. Is there any way we can achieve this using OOTB?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  Sessions in Salesforce can be locked to the original IP address though, which would prevent you from logging from two different locations.  You can also set sessions to have a 15 minute timeout, so if they logged in a second time, after a little bit, the first session would be terminated.